# AndroidManifest.xml is missing try reimporting the plugin

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, android-manifest, ads

I have a problem implementing google admob in unity.
I downloaded latest version of Unity plugin from github but there is missing xml manifest and i can't figure out how can i get that file. I tried reimporting several times but it does't work
Unity version is 2019.2.0f1, any help is appreciated.
here is the error log

[image: I fixed second error, main problem is the blue one]

I fixed second error, main problem is the blue one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried Junmo's solution above, and it looked good but was giving app ruining, apparently unrelated crashes once built to Android. So I would like to update that to what I finally found works;

Find the folder at

```
Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin
```

and rename it to

```
GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib
```

That seems to solve the error message, and not cause unknown crashes down the line. So far. We'll see how long Google keeps compatibility for this solution.

Comment: in my case this folder had the ```.androidlib``` suffix and i just removed it and worked!thanks

Comment: I just wanted to point out that renaming `GoogleMobileAdsPlugin` to `GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib` is **one and only** right solution here, see this [github issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/1493). If you still experience problems afterwards - consider doing a clean installation of `GoogleMobileAds` plugin. Your version is probably way to old.

Answer (score 6):

In the ManifestProcessor.cs file that gives me an error
The "manifestPath" value was "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib/AndroidManifest.xml".

The actual AndroidManifest file was solved by changing the value of "manifestPath" because it exists in "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin/AndroidManifest.xml".

```
string manifestPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib/AndroidManifest.xml");

=> string manifestPath = Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin/AndroidManifest.xml");
```

Comment: Not Working Bro

Comment: This almost works, but causes other issues. Per my answer below, I found it was better to rename the folder to match rather than alter the path in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Put manifest.xml file manually on require location, i am also getting this error i solved by manully put xml file on "...Assets\Plugins\Android\GoogleMobileAdsPlugin{XML FILE}" this location.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem when trying to click "Build And Run".
For some reason the problem disappeared when I clicked "Build" instead (and let it build to a file) and after that the "Build And Run" button worked also.

Answer (score 0):

For latest Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v7.0.0 or higher and Unity v2019 or higher

In the **ManifestProcessor.cs** file at **Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/** folder.

Need to change this variable manifest file path location.

**FROM**

```
MANIFEST_RELATIVE_PATH =  "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.androidlib/AndroidManifest.xml";
```

**TO**

```
MANIFEST_RELATIVE_PATH =  "Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin/AndroidManifest.xml";
```